# React Native StatusBar backgroundColor changes only after re-rendering the app

Tags: android, react-native, android-statusbar

I am trying to change the `backgroundColor` of ReactNative `StatusBar` component, and it doesn't change right away, but it changes when a component causes the app to re-render.

```
const AppStatusBar = ({ theme }) => {
  return (
    <StatusBar
      backgroundColor={theme.colors.background}
      barStyle={theme.dark
        ? AppConstants.LIGHT_CONTENT
        : AppConstants.DARK_CONTENT}
      translucent
    />
  );
};
```

**Expected:** StatusBar color changes.
**Actual result:** Changes only after the app re-renders.